# Regularize a graph while embedding the spectrum of adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrices

Given an irregular graph $G$ whose maximum degree is $d$, I am interested in producing a new graph $G'$ which is regular and has the spectrum of the adjacency spectrum of $G$ embedded in the spectrum of the adjacency matrix $G'$. Is there any work done to answer this kind of question?